# MATLAB Class-based unit tests: How to pass in variable to test

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I'm not sure how to pass in variables when executing a unit test. These variables were created from another function not placed within the unit test.

**Method 1:**

```
   classdef myTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
          properties
            A, B, C
          end
          methods (Test)
            function testDataCoverage(testCase)
              expSol = afunction(A, B, C)
              actSol = 10
              testCase.verifyEqual(testCase, actSol, expSol)
            end
          end
    end
```

I next tried to place the variable-creating function (getData) within the unit test but encountered this error:

> Concrete class myTest does not define a TestParameter property named
>   BNew for the dataCoverage method. Either implement the property or
>   define the class as Abstract.

**Method 2:**

```
classdef myTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase

      properties
      end

      methods (Test)

        function testDataCoverage(testCase)
           [A, B, C] = getData()
           expSol = afunction(A, B, C)
           actSol = 10
           testCase.verifyEqual(testCase, actSol, expSol)
        end

        function [A, B, C] = getData()
            ...code here...
        end

        function Sol = afunction(A, BNew, C)
            ...code here...
        end

      end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want to use is a [TestParameter](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.parameters.testparameter-class.html):

```
classdef myTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase

  properties (TestParameter)
    param = {1, 2};
  end

  methods (Test)
    function testDataCoverage(testCase, param)
        testCase.verifyEqual(param, 1);
    end
  end
 end
```

Matlab will then automatically create n test cases (for each entry in the cell-list one) where the param-parameter will be associated with a different entry of the TestParameter. Hence you will automatically loop over all of them. (Note: If you have more than one TestParamater per TestCase, you might want to look into ParameterCombination in the Matlab documentation...)

Those TestParameter can also be created by an (external) static method:
    classdef myTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase

```
  properties (TestParameter)
    param = myTest.getData();
  end

  methods (Test)
    function testDataCoverage(testCase, param)
        testCase.verifyEqual(param, 1);
    end
  end
  methods (Static)
    function data = getData()
        data = {1,2,3};
    end
  end
 end
```

Fiy: This external source will be only triggered once, until the class is parsed. It stays then within memory and matlab caches that state. If you read here some external configuration file, you might want to `clear all` to force a re-creation of that class.

Sub-answer: In your Method2 Block, `[A, B, C] = getData()` you are missing the self-reference `myTest.getData()` .

Comment: @Heigele thanks, but what if i don't want to hardcode param = {1, 2}, but rather pass in an already existing variable in the workspace containing data ?

Comment: That is not possible. You can't re-assign an existing variable to a test-parameter.

But you can use the same method that created your existing variable and use this to set the TestParamter. (As long as the method is static.)

Comment: Also that would not make sense in a testing-approach at all. You need to create all your test-data before actually executing your test. Why would you be dependent on a workspace variable?

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB R2018b just went out the door. In this release you now have the flexibility of injecting test parameter data into MATLAB Class-Based Test file without modifying the file.

The data is defined outside the test file in the MATLAB workspace. In your case, you would be able to do something like this:

```
classdef myTest< matlab.unittest.TestCase  
  properties (TestParameter)
    A = {1}; % default value for A
    B = {2}; % default value for B
    C = {3}; % default value for C
  end

  methods (Test)
    function testDataCoverage(testCase, A,B,C)
        expSol = afunction(A, B, C);
        actSol = 10;
        testCase.verifyEqual(testCase, actSol, expSol);
    end
  end

end


%Injecting values of A, B and C without modifying the test file
import matlab.unittest.parameters.Parameter;
import matlab.unittest.TestSuite;

>> params = Parameter.fromData( ...
    'A', {11}, ...
    'B', {21},...
    'C', {31}...
);

% Generating suites with the external data
>> suite = TestSuite.fromFile('mytest.m', 'ExternalParameters', params);

% Running test with external data 
>> run(suite)
```

Here is the detailed documentation:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testsuite.fromfile.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-external-parameters-in-parameterized-test.html